# Prevent insertion when extensions in both datatables are different and continue insertion when extensions in datatables are same using asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Below is my code which check for extensions and based on the extensions it will go into read method the problem in if both dt and dt1 rows data ends with doc and docx then it goes to readfiles method 
if one is doc and another is docx and vice-versa it will show a message that Both the selected Documents Should Have Same Extensions.

Suppose if i take 3 douments in pair that means totally 6 let us assume the data in two datatables is in this way

```
dt   dt1
doc  docx
doc  doc
docx doc
doc  docx
```

then for the first one it should show error message for the second one it should get inserted and for third and fourth it should not get inserted but it is not getting inserted i came to know that problem is with return in else if condition but if i am not using return after going into else block it is executing my next lines if code.How can i reslove this

```
        if (ddlstype.SelectedValue == "3")
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[0]["fname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".docx") && dt1.Rows[0]["lname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".docx"))
                {
                   ReadFiles();
                }

                else if (dt.Rows[0]["fname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".doc") && dt1.Rows[0]["lname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
                {
                   ReadFiles();
                }
                else if (dt.Rows[0]["fname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".doc") && dt1.Rows[0]["lname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".docx"))
                {
                    lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
                    lblerrmsg.Text = "Both the selected Documents Should Have Same Extensions";
                    return;
                }
                else if (basedt.Rows[0]["Bfname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".docx") && draftdt.Rows[0]["lname"].ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
                {
                    lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
                    lblerrmsg.Text = "Both the selected Documents Should Have Same Extensions";
                    return;
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Your example assumes 4 rows in `dt` and `dt1` but there is no loop to iterate thru those rows. All you are doing is trying to compare data in first row by doing `dt.Rows[0]` and `dt1.Rows[0]`. Also as per your logic and sample data it will return from the second`else if` block coz you have `doc` in `dt` and `docx` in `dt1`. So you need to use loop and remove return statements from the else if blocks.

Comment: already i am using loop and seperating the selected files into two datatables 
if the rows in the two datatables contain same extension it should insert else it should not get inserted  if we see in the above example 
second row in dt and dt1 have same extensions but it i not getting inserted it is directly showing error message

Comment: It will be good if you can show the code which use the loop. With whatever code you have shared I see that you are trying to compare data of only first row of both the tables. And as per your sample data the first rows does not match the criteria of ReadFiles that's why it goes to else if and returns from there. Did you try to debug the code and understand see the how the code is getting executed for the given sample data?

Comment: yes i think the problem with my code is i have all the rows in both the datatables but in else if i am using return i think this is stopping the checking for next rows in my datatable

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
HttpPostedFile postedFile = Request.Files[i];
if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
if (fileName.Contains("-b") || fileName.Contains("-B"))
{
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(fileName.ToLower().Replace("-b", ""));
}
if (fileName.Contains("-t") || fileName.Contains("-T"))
{
DataRow dr2 = dt1.NewRow();
dt1.Rows.Add(fileName.ToLower().Replace("-t", ""));
}
}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code and I am trying to suggest solution for them as following. And I am suggesting this based on the code and the details you have shared in the question.

In the code which has for loop you don't need to create instances of `DataRow`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = Request.Files[i];
    if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
        if (fileName.Contains("-b") || fileName.Contains("-B"))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(fileName.ToLower().Replace("-b", ""));
        }
        if (fileName.Contains("-t") || fileName.Contains("-T"))
        {
            dt1.Rows.Add(fileName.ToLower().Replace("-t", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

The above code assumes that the you will get equal number of files with their names having `-b` and `t` in them so that both `dt` and `dt1` will have same number of rows.
With that assumption I suggest you to iterate thru the rows of these tables and perform appropriate activity based on the contents of the rows.

```
if (ddlstype.SelectedValue == "3")
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var fileName1 = dt.Rows[i]["fname"].ToString().ToLower();
            var fileName2 = dt1.Rows[i]["fname"].ToString().ToLower();
            if ((fileName1.EndsWith(".docx") && fileName2.EndsWith(".docx"))
                  || 
                (fileName1.EndsWith(".doc") && fileName2.EndsWith(".doc")))
            {
                ReadFiles();
            }
            else
            {
                lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
                lblerrmsg.Text = "Both the selected Documents Should Have Same Extensions";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see there are datatables `basedt` and `draftdt`. I have removed from my code as I am not sure why they were used and I do not see any relevance of them.

This solution should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Define `its not working`. Any error? Did you debug the code? Did you understand the logic of my code?